# I cannot run facebook videos after messing about with terminal trying to speed it up

Tags: wireless, facebook, ath9k

The following is what I entered in command line

```
lshw -c network
sudo su
echo "option ath9k nohwcrypt=1" >>1etc/modprohobe.d/ath9k.conf
```

Comment: What about starting by reversing your change ? I assume that the file you changed is /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf, and not the filename you wrote above. Open it in a editor, and delete the last line (option ath9k nohwcrypt=1) .. if the file only contains this one line, you can delete it.

Comment: The two care completely unrelated. Changing something about the physical layer may slow the network connection down or break it altogether but it will not interrupt some application layer network services while others continue to function.

Comment: When I had problems with something specific as you is saying, it had to do with DNS settings. Can you see videos in other places?

Comment: Thank you.  I will try it. It is not all videos.